# Is it possible to get value form waspmote with Xbee S1 via Xbee pro S1

Tags: xbee

I'm working on a project. I need to send some data to my computer via Waspmote wirelessly. I have some Xbee modules with explorer, one XBee S1, one XBee Pro S1 and one XBee Pro S2. I've found some videos on youtube but they allways use the same version of the XBee. Can I make the connection with them or do I need the same version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only make communication between S1 or S2. an S2 Xbee use a different protocol than the S1.

It's like you speak spannish and I speak german :) we can't communicate.

Comment: What about Pro S1 and S1?

Comment: They can communicate between them only if they use the same protocol. I think that S1 pro use digimesh instead of 802.15.4 of the S1 :/
when you upload firmware with Xctu look which protocol it use